# how to assign variables to an object for submitting the Data using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My objective is to assign the variables to new object while submitting the data.

Here is the array of object as they appear while submitting:

```
experience: [
    {
        Organisation: "",
        ID: "",
        From: "",
        To: "",
        Skills: []
    },
    {
        Organisation: "",
        ID: "",
        From: "",
        To: "",
        Skills: []
    }
]
```

But i want the object should be in this way:

```
{
        organisationName: "",
        id: "",
        from: "",
        to: "",
        skills: []
    }
```

I have done in this way but output is not appearing in this appropriately.

```
handleSubmit = (e)=> {
e.preventDefault();
let obj = {
id: this.state.experience.map((item) => item.ID),
organisation: this.state.experience.map((item) => item.Organisation),
        from: this.state.experience.map((item) => item.From),
        to: this.state.experience.map((item) => item.To),
}
console.log("Object", obj)
}
```

Can anyone please help me to assign the values in a right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to use `Object.fromEntries` to map the entries and call `toLowerCase` on the keys:

```
const lowercaseKeys = obj => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, val]) => [key.toLowerCase(), val])
);
const obj = this.state.experience.map(lowercaseKeys);
```

If you also need to replace a particular key with another, use `.replace`:

```
const lowercaseKeys = obj => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, val]) => [
      key.toLowerCase().replace('organisation', 'organisationName'),
      val
    ])
);
const obj = this.state.experience.map(lowercaseKeys);
```

Comment: But, we have ID as two letters capitalize

Comment: `toLowerCase` will lower case all text it was called on. `'ID'.toLowerCase() === 'id'`

Comment: @ CertainPerformance -  I apologize, Here we have an issue, i didn't posted before. Organisation name is changing. Instead of "Organisation" we have "organistionName".

Comment: Use `.replace` to replace one string with another

Comment: I've one more query? Can you assist me ?

Comment: What is the query?